# Elasticsearch _id search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently using elasticsearch 1.3 and hope to get advice on the below question. 
I understand that I can execute http://localhost:9200/[index_name]/[index_type]/[_id] using Sense to search for a particular document in the index, but I have documents where the _id has # symbols which Sense couldn't find them. I tried to change the # to %23 (in javascript) and managed to find the document. I would like to check whether will Analyzer helps? I am so sure if I understand the elasticsearch's analyzer correctly.

Comment: The reason is simply because your id contains characters that need to be URL-encoded (`#`=> `%23`), this has nothing to do with analyzers

Comment: @Val thanks for the response. Can I know whether is there any workaround beside changing it to %23? I asked this question because there might be other special characters which might appear in the _id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need run your ID through an [URL-encoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) before adding it to your URL or you can also search for it using the [`ids` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) like this without having to encode it:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": ["2323#23423"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I am able to get it. Able to do the delete part using the same way -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/docs-delete-by-query.html. thank you for the advice

Comment: can I check with you how can I do the ids query for update?

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question ;-)